Graph API Facebook publishing_phase post
The result I get from ID
Code
  public String upVideoJson(String token, String mess, String urlVideo, String times) {
    String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/me/videos";
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    String videoId = null;
    try {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        String encodedMess = new String(mess.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
        builder.addTextBody("access_token", token, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        builder.addTextBody("description", encodedMess, ContentType.create("text/plain", "ISO-8859-1"));
        builder.addTextBody("file_url", urlVideo, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(times)) {
        builder.addTextBody("scheduled_publish_time", times, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        builder.addTextBody("published", Boolean.toString(false));
        }
        HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();
        httpPost.setEntity(multipart);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(responseString);
        if (jsonResponse.has("id")) {
            videoId = jsonResponse.getString("id");
        } else {
            System.out.println(token);
            System.out.println(jsonResponse);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new CustomException();
    }
    return videoId;
}

I scheduled the post but until now it still hasn't appeared on the Facebook page. When I use the ID to get the permalink_url, only I can see the video, like published = false. Can anyone help me solve the problem?

Sounds like you have not taken your app "live" yet, and it it still in dev mode. As long as the app is in dev mode, only people with a role in the app will be able to see any content that was created via it.

Please try not to post images of text.

If I don't use scheduled_publish_time, I can still post normally. I have selected development mode in the Facebook application.
